# Filter duplicate rows based on a condition in Pandas

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I have the below dataframe where there are duplicate rows based on a column "Reason".

```
No   Reason  
123  -
123  -
345  Bad Service
345  -
546  Bad Service
546  Poor feedback
```

I have subsetted these rows based on

```
df_duplicates = df[df['No'].duplicated() == True]
```

I am trying to loop over the above subset of rows and filter them only when the "Reason" for the corresponding duplicated row is both missing OR if any one is missing.

Hence the result would be

```
No   Reason  
123  -
123  -
345  Bad Service
345  -
```

I am trying to loop over it and then do it per pair. Not sure whether there is an efficient way to do this in Pandas. Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> filter them only when the "Reason" for the corresponding duplicated row is both missing OR if any one is missing.

You can do:

```
df[df['Reason'].eq('-').groupby(df['No']).transform('any')]
#or df[df['Reason'].isna().groupby(df['No']).transform('any')]
```

---

```
    No       Reason
0  123            -
1  123            -
2  345  Bad Service
3  345            -
```

Comment: Too fast too furious. I'm still reading the question :-)

Comment: @anky: thank you for your answer. Is there a way to include the rows where values are same as well. For example, if they have "bad service" in both rows, then I would prefer them in the result set

Comment: @user3447653 in that case you can try doing `out = df[(df['Reason'].eq('-')|df.duplicated(['No','Reason'],keep=False)).groupby(df['No']).transform('any')]` for nans, replace `.eq('-')` with `.isna()`

Comment: @user3447653 Were you able to use the code I posted in comments?